# Float calculation showing difference. Positive showing negative?

Tags: c#

I am calculating the difference between two numbers. If the calculation ends up being 5 - 10, it equals to "-5". If this is the case I need results to display/equal to "+5" , with the "+" sign.

I basically need reverse. So same if 10 - 5 quals to "5" I need it to display as "+5"

Code below I am using:

```
float rowresults = ROW1 - ROW2;
Textbox.text = rowresults.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Math.Abs is what you are looking for:

```cs
float rowresults = Math.Abs(ROW1 - ROW2);
```

And to add the "+"-sign to the front of the text (without changing your elsewise existing behaviour):

```cs
Textbox.text = "+" + rowresults.ToString();
```